# What is the difference between Ruby and Ruby on Rails in terms of limitations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am wanting to learn a new programming language, and am wondering what the difference is between the two beyond the fact that one is a framework based on Ruby and one is an actual language. What are the limitations of the two languages?

Comment: http://bit.ly/16wHbqm

Answer (score 4):

Ruby is a scripting language, as are Python and Perl.

Ruby on Rails is a Web app framework that is built on the scripting 
language Ruby.

Ruby on Rails makes it easy to use the language Ruby to write stuff that 
makes a dynamic database driven website work (like a wiki, or a social 
networking site).

Rails (not ruby itself) is proud to be "Opinionated Software".

What this means in practice is that the authors of rails have a certain target audience in mind (themselves basically) and aim rails specifically at that. If X feature isn't needed for that target audience, it doesn't get added.

Off the top of my head, things that rails explicitly doesn't support that people may care about:

- Foreign keys in databases
- SOAP web services (since rails 2.0)
- Connections to multiple database servers at once

That said, it is very easy to extend rails with plugins, and there are plugins which add all of the above functionality to rails, and a lot more, so I wouldn't really count these as limits.

The only other caveat is that rails is built around the idea of creating CRUD web applications using MVC. If you're trying to do something which is NOT a CRUD web app (like twitter, which is actually a messaging system, or if you are insane and want to use a model like ASP.NET webforms) then you will also encounter problems. In this case you're better off not using rails, as you're essentially trying to build a boat out of bicycle parts.

In all likelihood, the problems you will run into that can't just be fixed with a quick plugin or a day or 2 of coding are all inherent problems with the underlying C Ruby runtime (memory leaks, green threads, crap performance, etc).

Comment: Wow. A real ruby fanboy are we. If the problem is not solvable in two days, it is an inherent problem of the C ruby runtime. Wow!

Comment: Note: Ruby has several gems which you can use to communicate with external SOAP services - which can be used from Rails. Rails however does not support creating SOAP interfaces to your app. 

Also ActiveRecord was not built for multiple databases but can be easily extended to incorporate multiple databases. Other ORM's such as Mongoid support multiple sources out of the box.